# What is the definition of a statement implying or being equivalent to another statement given a background theory?

Tags: logic

I understand what it means for a statement $P$ to imply, or be equivalent to, another statement $Q$. However, in mathematics, two statements are often not equivalent to each other by themselves, but only given a background theory $T$. For example, given the background of ZF set theory, the axiom of choice is equivalent to the statement that every set can be well-ordered. So, my question is, what is the rigorous definition of the statement "Given background assumptions $T$, $P$ implies/is equivalent to, $Q$"?

Comment: The rigorous definition is that there is a finite set $S \subseteq T$ and a formal proof that the statements in $S \cup \{P\}$ logically entail $Q$. In other words, it's the statement that $P \to Q$ is a theorem of $T$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bram28's [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4329743/28111) is absolutely correct. However, I think it is worth pointing out a subtlety which arises if we look at weaker background logics than first-order logic. For simplicity I'll talk only about **propositional** logic(s) since already these present enough complexity for the situation to be interesting.

In classical propositional logic, it makes to say that (propositional) sentences $\alpha,\beta$ are equivalent modulo a (again, propositional) theory $T$ iff $$T\vdash \alpha\leftrightarrow\beta.$$ This is, however, dependent on having a particular connective ("$\leftrightarrow$") in our language. What if we don't have it?

Well, the following alternative definition leaps to mind: $\alpha$ is equivalent modulo $T$ to $\beta$ iff $$T\cup\{\alpha\}\vdash\beta\quad\mbox{and}\quad T\cup\{\beta\}\vdash\alpha.$$ In fact, this is really *prior* (in my opinion) to the $\leftrightarrow$-based definition, the two being connected by the **deduction theorem**. This gives us a notion of equivalence modulo a theory even in very limited situations - say, when we only have access to the connective "$\wedge$" (functional completeness is a *privilege*, not a *right*, and we may not have eaten sufficiently many lima beans recently :P).

However, this is really just the start of the story. Once we start questioning our underlying propositional apparatus, we will inevitably be led to the idea of **algerbaic logic** and in particular **algebraization**. It turns out that, broadly speaking, the following are equivalent for a logic (in the appropriate sense) $\mathcal{L}$:

- $\mathcal{L}$ has a "well-behaved" algebraic semantics (e.g. Boolean algebras for classical propositional logic).
- $\mathcal{L}$ has a "well-behaved" notion of logical equvialence (involving the so-called *Leibniz operator* $\Omega$).

See [Blok/Pigozzi's *Algebraizable logics*](https://bookstore.ams.org/memo-77-396/) or the introduction of [Czelakowski's *Protoalgebraic logics*](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-94-017-2807-2) for more on this topic. Again, **this type of subtlety does not arise when "working over $\mathsf{ZF}$" or similar**, but for anyone interested in how logic works "under the hood" it's worth being aware of.

Answer (score 5):

Given some theory $T$, we can say that statement $P$ is '$T$-equivalent' to $Q$ if and only if $P \leftrightarrow Q$ is a theorem of $T$ (or if you want: can be derived from its axioms). Or formally: $T \vDash P \leftrightarrow Q$